# Add persistent static route - AWS Instance

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, vpn, routing

I have a AWS Instance, running Ubuntu. I have a static route which works just great

sudo route add -net 192.168.10.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 172.31.16.5 dev eth0

However, whenever I reboot, the route is gone. I should be able to make is presistent by going to sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces, but cannot(creates a boot error).

How can I enter my route to run every time the AWS instance reboots?

Comment: You can create an `@reboot` line in root's crontab. Be careful as this will not work if you shut down/power on your instance.

Comment: This is related to your question here: https://superuser.com/questions/1234456/aws-openvpn-routing - Adding a static route on your instance is not the answer. I would suggest seeing your other question through to completion.